# Freeradius and WHMCS for VPN your opinion needed

Tags: vpn, whmcs, freeradius

I am using WHMCS and bought the Free Radius plugin in order to manage VPN service.

I am trying to assess the pro and cons of using Freeradius Vs a Custom solution.

In my opinion Freeradius brings the following cons :

Huge overhead
Complex and not well coded: difficult to improve.
In case of bug, very hard to fix, no maintenability.
Impossible or complex and expensive to add functionality or evolve the code.
Centralized authentification system, will add between 500ms to 5s lag for the authentification (client connection).
If the central server is down, no client can connect to any server.

Do you think it is a good idea to choose not to use Freeradius and code my own solution for WHMCS in order to manage authentication and user management ?

Trying to assess the pro and cons.

Thx for your opinion

Answer (score 1):

Don't get too caught up on it adding 500ms for the authentication. That's nothing, and won't be noticeable

You mention single point of failure should radius go down. Radius works from MySQL as well as a built in flat-file database (the freeradius module makes use of this MySQL database anyway) so you can have a master-master configuration for your database, with two radius nodes set up in failover.

I fell in love with digitalocean which make this even easier with floating IPs. And all controlled via an API :-)

freeradius is very widely used within this industry, so that should say something about it's stability for you